# Javascript pull search completion from web service

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I'm a bit new to Javascript and I want to do something I feel like should be pretty simple.  I have a web completion service built and I just need to get those completions into the page.  I basically want something like this:

```
<script>
  function(search_string){
    http.request('www.fake.com/search_complete/' + search_string, function(response) {
      response = JSON.parse(response);
      //do something with parsed data
    });
  }
</script>
<input type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
```

Comment: I think you're far away from destination. Choose a library (e.g. jQuery). Choose a UI library. Get to know about Same-Origin-Policy, CORS, JSONP, ... You should make smaller steps IMO. Are you coming from Node.js programming? At least your JavaScript code looks good so far :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to make a request and use the data returned? If so, just make an ajax request and update the html with the data you get back

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST','http://www.fake.com/whatever.php?val1='+search_string,true);
request.send();
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status=200){
      //The request has been completed, handle the data
      var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
   }
}
```

Comment: but how can I get the search_string from the html input field?

Comment: give the field an id attribute and get the value using that, like          <input type="text" id="search_field"> for the html and               var search_string = document.getElementById('search_field').value; for the javascript

Answer (score 1):

This must help. Example integration of jQuery UI autocomplete from remote web service.
http://salman-w.blogspot.in/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery:

```
$.ajax({type: "GET", dataType: 'json', contentType: "application/json", url: "yoururl", success:         function (data) {
        //data is a javascript object that contains the data returned by your webservice json
    }, error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Display a generic error for now.
        alert("Error: " + xhr + "   " + status + "   " + error);
      }});
```

This code will make a call to a webservice using ajax and javascript.  It will return the data from the webservice in the data object.